# jquery datatable formatting gone after reloading using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a partial view which when first loads with the controller, loads the data in a jquery datatable as shown below. However once I run an event and call the partial action method, the data is still returned but the formatting is gone:
[image: when full page loads]
[image: partialview return]

Code to return partialView:

```
public PartialViewResult ListAppointments(string _userId)
{
    var userId =  Convert.ToInt32(_userId);
    var o = (from s in db.tblAppointments.ToList()
             where s.UserId == userId
             select new AppointmentViewModel { AppointmentInstructorName = s.InstructorName, AppointmentLessonAddress = s.Address, LessonDateTime = s.LessonDate, UserId = s.UserId, Id = s.ID });

    return PartialView(o);
}
```

jQuery call:

```
function success(result) {
    var Id = $('#UserId').val();
    var data = JSON.stringify({"_userId": Id});
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Appointment")",
        data: data,
        success: function (result2) { $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2); }
    });
}
```

Razor where the partial view is:

```
<div class="panel-heading tabbable" tabindex="0"><h1>List of all appointments (including historical) for user</h1></div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="partialViewAppointments">
        @Html.Partial("ListAppointments", Model.Appointments)
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Lesson Date and Time</th>
        <th>Address (if different)</th>
        <th></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Lesson Date and Time</th>
        <th>Address (if different)</th>
        <th></th>

    </tr>
</tfoot>


<tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var info in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@info.Id</td>
                <td>@info.AppointmentInstructorName</td>
                <td>@info.LessonDateTime</td>

                <td>@info.AppointmentLessonAddress</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Appointment", new { id = info.Id }, null)</td>
            </tr>

        }
    }

</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're replacing the HTML with the result from the server:

```
$("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2);
```

What's being sent from the server is just an HTML `table`, with no knowledge of jQuery DataTables or any other plugin.  After the data is placed in the DOM, you would need to initialize that plugin again:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Appointment")",
    data: data,
    success: function (result2) {
        $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2);

        $('#example').DataTable(); // <-- right here
        // Using whatever options were used the first time, of course
    }
});
```

Comment: thankyou. that seems to have worked. i knew that i was doing this but had no clue how to fix this. i tried the datatable example but not in the success function and applied before the results are returned.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the entire DOM within the container, rather than using the DataTable api to update it's data store.

You have two options:

1 - the bruteforce solution, reinitialize the DT :

```
function success(result) {
        var Id = $('#UserId').val();
        var data = JSON.stringify({"_userId": Id});
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Appointment")",
            data: data,
            success: function (result2) { $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2).Datatable(); }
        });
    }
```

Option 2 - Learn the API around aaData (DataTable internal data store). You could do this @ a per row iteration via the `row().data()` api https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()

Alternatively - get to understand aaData store within the Datatable 
http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side -- note this is the `legacy` api docs but it is still relevant to some extent